# Using nginx to deny certain requests by server name

Tags: nginx

I am trying to use my nginx configuration to deny requests that match a certain pattern, but only for a certain server name. I am not sure how to do this, and despite that [IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) I tried to compare `$server_name` with the server I don't want requests from and return 403. That approach didn't work at all.

The request I want to prevent goes through a URL rewrite. The nginx server config handles multiple domains as the `server_name` directive.

```
location / {
         try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
         rewrite ^ /index.php;
}
```

I want to prevent the request for `user` and `user/register` but only if the server name used is `example.com`

I'm kind of stuck here because I've never had to do anything like this.

Here is the current nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 192.168.0.10:80;
        server_name server.intranet company.com;
        access_log /home/company/access_log;
        error_log /home/company/error_log;
        root /home/company/intranet;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {                                                                        
                allow all;                                                                              
                access_log off;                                                                         
        }                                                                                               

        location ~* \.(txt|log) {                                                                       
                allow 127.0.0.1;                                                                        
                deny all;                                                                               
        }                                                                                               

        location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {                                                                      
                allow 192.168.0.0/16;                                                                   
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
                return 403;
        }

        location ~ (^|/)\. {
                return 403;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }

        location @rewrite {
                rewrite ^ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/company-socket;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem why you are looking for a solution like this? Isn't a default virtualhost that denies everything enough? And then `location` blocks for `/user` URI in virtual host for that domain?

Comment: I have a site on two domains, I don't want people to be able to log in on one domain. I want one nginx server block for both sites. The problem is only users on the internal network should be able to log in.

Comment: Make two separate server blocks.

Comment: `I want one nginx server block for both sites` - Sounds like a problem of your own making; it's trivial to solve by _not_ doing that.

Comment: I recommend using `include` to make your config easier. I don't see any probs here though.